# Stripe - How to use the listing API?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) mentions that you can use the "listing API" to page through results when there are more than 100 returned. However I don't see any mention of how to use the listing API in their reference. Right now I am changing the offset parameter with each of my calls but this gets cumbersome. Does anyone know how to use the listing API?

Comment: Control pagination with offsets in the listing seems the way it's supposed to work

Comment: It appears that this is the only way to page through results - by changing the offset parameter for each function call.